# Mustache.js function for format number

Tags: jquery, mustache

I'm trying to use mustache.js in my jquery code.
Unfortunately I have a problem to format a numeric value with a function.

```
var data = {
  "price": 12000.00,
  "format": function () {
     return function (text, render) {
       return Number( render(text) ).toLocaleString( "it-IT", { maximumFractionDigits: 2 } ) + ' &euro;';
     }
   }
}

var template = "{{#format}}Formatted price : {{price}} {{/format}}";
var text = Mustache.render(template, data);
//output --> NaN €
```

I tried to use parseInt instead of Number but with the same result.
How could I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache is not made for these kinds of things, because it is intended to be logic-less. It does support custom functions, but it won't be very elegant. In Mustache it's expected that you do all formatting *before* you pass the data to the renderer.

The process for a Mustache template like this `{{#format}}{{price}}{{/format}}` is:

- `format` is called, it gets the raw text (`'{{price}}'`) as argument #1 and a special `render()` function as argument #2.
- You call `render(text)` (this results in whatever `{{price}}` evaluates to)
- You make modifications to this result and return it.

This means you have a number in your model. `render(text)` turns it into a string. You then have to parse that string back into a number again and re format it according to your locale. That's very a roundabout way of doing this, it really will be much easier if you format the number up-front and don't try shoehorn this into Mustache.

For posterity, here is how this would look using Mustache:

```js
var data = {
  price: 12000.5,
  format: function () {
    return function (text, render) {
      var result = render(text);
      return parseFloat(result).toLocaleString("it-IT", {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      });
    }
  }
}

var template = "Formatted price: {{#format}}{{price}}{{/format}} €";
var result = Mustache.render(template, data);
document.querySelector("#output").textContent = result;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I will follow your suggestion and will first format the data to be passed to mustache. thanks for the support